# jquery mmenu disabling a links on the page

Tags: jquery, mmenu

I'm using a mmenu on a jquery mobile page.

I have a html page with two pages with unique ids. I have a link on the first page to the second page as such:

...

Both pages are setup appropriately with roles and content identifiers.

I also have a mmenu on the page. When the mmenu initialization code runs, the link to the second page doesn't work:

var $menu = $('nav#menu');
$menu.mmenu({slidingSubmenus:false});

When I comment out these two lines, it works fine.

It looks like mmenu is preventing default behavior on "a" tags.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Add some html or css code. Also place you javascript  in a script box

Comment: The javascript was posted. That's all there is to it, just the menu initialization. The html was taken from here:

http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.5/pages-multi-page/

It's very simple html.

Comment: Did you solve this?  I am using jquery mobile 1.4.5 and have exactly the same issue.  No page navigation using links.